# creating a database class using the multimap class in c++

Tags: c++, stl, class-design, multimap

I'm working with C++ for a project. I need to store a pair (string,integer) and access them based on the string. The multimap class seems perfect for that. I am trying to make my own class, database, which will include methods to find the average and count of all the integers associated with a particular string. However, I am a bit confused on the initial constructor. My database should be created when `database data();` is called, but it comes up with a huge error.

Here is an implementation of the constructor in database.cpp

```
    database::database()
{
  data = new multimap<string,int>; // allocates new space for the database  
  *data["asdf"]= 0; // adds a point. not needed...?                         
}
```

Also, the database.h file looks like so.

```
 private:
  multimap<string,double> *data;
```

The error is rather dense, and I can't decipher it, but when I run g++ database.cpp test.cpp this comes out.

```
$ g++ database.cpp test.cpp 
database.cpp: In constructor ‘database::database()’:
database.cpp:11: error: cannot convert ‘std::multimap<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > >*’ to ‘std::multimap<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double> > >*’ in assignment
database.cpp:12: error: invalid types ‘std::multimap<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double> > >*[const char [5]]’ for array subscript
```

Edit:

I forgot to add, thanks for the help!

Rusty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare `data` as a `multimap<string,double>*` but then you try to assign to `data` a `multimap<string,int>*` -- reconcile these.

As an aside, `database data();` is not what you want -- it is in fact a declaration of a nullary function named `data` with a return type of `database`; use `database data;` instead.

Comment: Good catch on 'database data();'. It should be noted that 'database * data = new database()' works correctly although the final parentheses are unnecessary.